# Can we use Autonomous Database (ATP/ADW) with private endpoints to deploy an ODI Marketplace repository?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Can we use Autonomous Database (ATP/ADW) with private endpoints to deploy an ODI Marketplace repository or does the database have to be publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no restriction toward using this option. ODI and ATP/ADW will follow the OCI network configuration, routing, security lists etc. The use of the private endpoint allows for better security and simple management of the network services used by the Autonomous Database instances.

For more information about Private endpoints refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/security-restrict-private-endpoint.html#GUID-D12F124A-9B71-4B83-B157-63F1057072FF).

As ODI typically requires vnc access, you will have the following type of options to configure ODI:

1. ODI in a public subnet with public IP and using a routing table that has an internet gateway. This subnet, if in the same VCN, should have a security list configured to allow traffic inbound to the subnet of the ATP/ADW instances.
2. Configure ODI in the same private subnet as a bastion instance, to create vnc connections and forward from the bastion instance to the local client (to access ODI Studio). ODI and the database will reside in the same subnet and the security list should only allow routing of database traffic in the private subnet.
3. Similar to option 1 but with the use of a different VCN. Deploy ODI in    a different VCN from the ADB instance, and configure [local VCN Peering](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/localVCNpeering.htm) to route traffic between the VCNs, and then the security list to allow the traffic between the different VCN subnets.